# What is the difference between a method and a protocol

Tags: objective-c, protocols

They say that a protocol is a method, but it's different from a method.  So exactly, what does it do and what is the difference between a method and a protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Objective-C** each class has an ***interface***, a list of method defenitions which that class implements, and an ***implementation***, the source for each of those method defenitions.

A ***protocol*** is a list of method definitions. A class can support a protocol by implementing the methods it defines.

Answer (score 5):

A protocol is most definitely NOT a method!  A protocol is a set of methods that a class implements when conforming to that protocol.  It is similar to a Java interface.  See this informative discussion:  [Objective-C versus Java Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990360/differences-between-java-interfaces-and-objective-c-protocols)

Answer (score 0):

A protocol is a set of methods that objects of a class may implement.

Let's say you have a protocol that consists of a method A and a method B, then an object conforms to that protocol if it implements method A and method B.

It's also possible for a protocol to include optional methods which are not required to be implemented.