# Why do we need protocol in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

The necessity for protocols are to abstract the methods of classes which are not hierarchically related.

The similar things also can be done with the help a class (interface) which encompasses all those methods and subclass them ? (This is not really possible due to the Multiple inheritance problem since a class has to be derived already from NSObject.ignore the NSProxy case)

What special things that protocols can do than a class?

Are protocols trying to solve only the multiple inheritance problem?

Comment: you could find answer in google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protocols main advantage is, that they describe what a object should be able to do, without enforcing subclassing. In languages that dont have multiple inheritance such a mechanism is needed, if you want others programmers be able to use your classes. (see [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html))

For an instance Java has [something similar, called interfaces.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990360/differences-between-java-interfaces-and-objective-c-protocols)

This means a huge advantage, as it is very easy to build dynamic systems, as I can allow other developers to enhance my classes via a clearly defined protocol.

A practical example:
I am just designing a REST API and I am providing a Objective-C client library.
As my api requires information about the user, I add a protocol

```
@protocol VSAPIClientUser <NSObject>
-(NSString *)lastName;
-(NSString *)firstName;
-(NSString *)uuid;
@end
```

Anywhere I need this user information, I will have an basic id-object, that must conform to this protocol

```
-(void)addUserWithAttributes:(id<VSAPIClientUser>)user;
```

You can read this line as: "I don't care, what kind of object you provide here, as long as it knows about `lastName`, `firstName` and `uuid`". So I have no idea, how the rest of that object looks like — and I don't care.

As the library author I can use this safely:

```
 NSDictionary *userAttributes = @{@"last_name" : [user lastName],
                                  @"first_name": [user firstName],
                                        @"uuid": [user uuid]};
```

---

BTW: I wouldn't call the absence of multi-inheritance a problem. It is just another design.

> “[…] If I revisited that decision today, I might even go so far as to remove single inheritance as well. Inheritance just isn’t all that important. Encapsulation is OOP’s lasting contribution.” — Brad Cox was asked, why Objective-C doesn’t have multiple inheritance. (Masterminds of Programming: Conversations with the Creators of Major Programming Languages, p. 259)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative view....

Object-oriented programming's most basic value comes from being able to model real-world relationships **directly** as opposed to translating them into abstract and vaguely-equivalent computer-world constructs.  Wherever a language requires you to think about the implementation of a solution in different terms than those you can use to describe your problem, it is flawed as an OOP tool.  (Note that I didn't say 'useless'. :) )

Real-world objects have various roles that depend on context.  Those roles can have state.  Therefore, I agree that lack of multiple-inheritance is an impediment to ease of modelling.  Objective-C protocols, Java interfaces, and the claim that you should prefer composition to inheritance are all denials of a fundamental part of the OOP advantage.

Comment: I dont see your point: obj-c protocols and java interfaces make it much easier to model huge and dynamic systems than multiple-inheritance. actually multi-inheritance might mislead people to put too much in one class instead of using good patterns. I am quite sure that this was the reason for omitting multi-inheritance when C# — as the newest incarnation of an C-based OOP-language — was designed.

Comment: Opinions differ...especially about "easy". :) My point is that if you value having congruence between problem space elements and solution space elements, any language constructs that exist solely as implementation conveniences interfere with that goal. (If that goal isn't important to your development then, obviously, you may not care.) As for putting too much into a single class, I've **never** seen that done in C++ to the degree that's common in iOS view controllers with their long lists of implemented protocols.

Comment: a long list of protocol methods does not indicate any problem. as long as they belong to the same task. also just 2 of tableviews's datasource and delegate method must be implemented. the rest are hooks you can use for any kind of customization. as long as your controller doesnt inherit from UITableView controller, this allows you to deal with the tableView as a black box, while inheritance always is white boxing: you need to know certain internals of the parent class (like for the UITableViewContoller: it has a tableView attached to it.)

Comment: You mentioned too much code (or responsibility) inside a single class.  I'm telling you the most common place I've seen it.  [shrug]

Comment: too much code is not defined by a lunber of lines or something like that, but by code, that doesnt belong to the same task.

Comment: I think you're talking about the same thing I was when I expanded the reference to code to include "responsibility".

Answer (score 0):

One of many uses of C++ abstract classes is, among their other uses, to define interfaces (to specify reusable contracts).  There are however also other programming languages, such as Objective C that have a separate concept for interfaces in this sense; in Objective C, it is called protocols.

A wide use of such a construct does require a way of attaching more than one contract to an object; and if such interfaces are allowed to inherit from each another, this has to be multiple inheritance to be useful.

However, this is not the same thing as multiple inheritance between classes.

Protocols are not trying to solve the multiple inheritance problem.  They are trying to separate contract specification from object (data+code) specification.  They can actually do much *less* than a class (if you ignore the multiple inheritance aspect) and that's why they exist as a separate concept.

Implementing a protocol is generally a much less restrictive (safer) proposition to consider than inheriting from a class.